# How can I put an animation in the path of my circular progress bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have a circular progress bar that has two paths. On one of those paths increases in length as the data comes in, eventually turning the entire circle red.

SVG HTML

```
<path d="M 50,50 m 0,-47 a 47,47 0 1 1 0,94 a 47,47 0 1 1 0,-94" stroke="#A9B0B7" stroke-width="4" fill-opacity="0">
  </path>

  <path id="path2" d="M 50,50 m 0,-47 a 47,47 0 1 1 0,94 a 47,47 0 1 1 0,-94" stroke="#EB483F" stroke-width="6" fill-opacity="0" style="stroke-dasharray: 295.416, 295.416; stroke-dashoffset: 250"></path>
  </svg>
```

CSS (Just makes loading of red path smoother)

```
#path2 {
  -webkit-transition-property: stroke-dashoffset; /* Safari */
  transition-property: stroke-dashoffset;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s; /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.viewbox {
  width: 50%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z5yb5kr9/

I would like for the remaining gray portion to have an animation such as a small div running through it lighting it up. Something similar to this

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_loader

I believe that I need to add some sort of keyframe animation and put the div inside the Path of the svg but I am not sure exactly what the method for doing so is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way you could do the pulsing anumation on a circular progress bar.

In order to get the pulse effect showing inside a growing progress bar, the most obvious way is to create the pulse effect as it's own animation, then mask it with the actually progress arc.

Firstly, let's start with the plain red progress bar.  I've added a grow animation for testing.

```css
.viewbox {
  width: 50%;
}

#progress {
  stroke-dasharray: 296 296;
  stroke-dashoffset: 296;
  animation: grow 5s ease-out infinite;
}

@keyframes grow {
  100% { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
}
```

```html
<svg class="viewbox" viewBox="0 0 100 100">

  <circle id="grey" cx="50" cy="50" r="47"
          transform="rotate(-90 50 50)"
          stroke="#A9B0B7" stroke-width="4" fill="none"/>
  
  <circle id="progress" cx="50" cy="50" r="47"
          transform="rotate(-90 50 50)" pointer-events="all"
          stroke="#EB483F" stroke-width="6" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```

Next, let's create our pulse animation which mimics the [example you gave in an answer that was deleted](http://materializecss.com/preloader.html).

```css
.viewbox {
  width: 50%;
}

#pulse {
  stroke-dasharray: 0 0 0 296;
  animation: pulse 1.5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
   33% { stroke-dasharray: 0   0 148 296; }
   66% { stroke-dasharray: 0  50 200 296; }
  100% { stroke-dasharray: 0 296   0 296; }
}
```

```html
<svg class="viewbox" viewBox="0 0 100 100">

  <rect width="100" height="100" fill="#EB483F"/>
  <circle id="pulse" cx="50" cy="50" r="47"
          transform="rotate(-90 50 50)" pointer-events="all"
          stroke="white" stroke-width="8" stroke-opacity="0.4" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```

It's just a translucent circle (with a dash animation) on a red background.

The penultimate step is to convert the first example into the form we need for a mask. In masks, black is transparent and white is opaque.

```css
.viewbox {
  width: 50%;
}

#progress {
  stroke-dasharray: 296 296;
  stroke-dashoffset: 296;
  animation: grow 5s ease-out infinite;
}

@keyframes grow {
  100% { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
}
```

```html
<svg class="viewbox" viewBox="0 0 100 100">

  <rect width="100" height="100" fill="black"/>
  
  <circle id="progress" cx="50" cy="50" r="47"
          transform="rotate(-90 50 50)" pointer-events="all"
          stroke="white" stroke-width="6" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```

The final step is to combine the last two steps. We turn the previous step into a proper `<mask>` and use it to mask the pulse animation.

```css
.viewbox {
  width: 50%;
}

#progress {
  stroke-dasharray: 296 296;
  stroke-dashoffset: 296;
  animation: grow 5s ease-out infinite;
}

@keyframes grow {
  100% { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
}

#pulse {
  stroke-dasharray: 0 0 0 296;
  animation: pulse 1.5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
   33% { stroke-dasharray: 0   0 148 296; }
   66% { stroke-dasharray: 0  50 200 296; }
  100% { stroke-dasharray: 0 296   0 296; }
}
```

```html
<svg class="viewbox" viewBox="0 0 100 100">

  <defs>
    <mask id="progress-as-mask" >
      <rect width="100" height="100" fill="black"/>
      <circle id="progress" cx="50" cy="50" r="47"
              transform="rotate(-90 50 50)" pointer-events="all"
              stroke="white" stroke-width="6" fill="none"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <circle id="grey" cx="50" cy="50" r="47"
          transform="rotate(-90 50 50)"
          stroke="#A9B0B7" stroke-width="4" fill="none"/>

  <g mask="url(#progress-as-mask)">
    <rect width="100" height="100" fill="#EB483F"/>
    <circle id="pulse" cx="50" cy="50" r="47"
            transform="rotate(-90 50 50)" pointer-events="all"
            stroke="white" stroke-width="8" stroke-opacity="0.4" fill="none"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

You weren't entirely clear on what you wanted. But hopefully, this has at least got you started.